# Page down skips too far on stackoverflow.blog

Tags: bug, blog

I was reading the newest Stack Overflow Blog today ("3 Ways You Can Be an Ally to Women in Tech"), and was *very* confused, because I only saw two ways (assuming the bold headers are the aforementioned ways).

I realized eventually that there was a third: but it was never visible on the screen when I paged down!

This is what I was looking at for the second page of the article; see how the first point is visible, and all the way to the end of that paragraph is visible.

[image: First Page]

Then I hit page down, and see this:

[image]

Notice how the "Mentor Your Peers" subheader is *not* visible.  It's skipped entirely by a pagedown.

This is on Windows 7, Chrome 61.0.3163.100.

Comment: I'm entirely open to this being a bug in Chrome, by the way; this isn't the first time I've seen an issue like this, ESPN works pretty much the same way, which is why I figured to look for it.

Comment: then you're at the wrong place. if espn have the same issue, then it's your browser.

Comment: @redhand Not necessarily.  It could well be that they both do the same "wrong" thing.  The fact that *most* sites work properly suggests to me that it's more likely an implementation detail on the webpage's end.